# 404 error on Spring hello world program

Tags: spring

I was creating a basic Hello World program.  Everything I coded appears to be correct, but the program is not working.

Servlet web.xml is :

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Dispatcher Servlet is :

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

calling callingDate.html :

```html
<body>
    <p>
        <a href="showdate.html">click here to get DATE TIME.</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

called showing.jsp :

```jsp
<body>
    today date time string is :
    <span>${date}</span>
</body>
```

controller class :

```java
package com.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/showdate")
public class DateShowController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showmethod(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("date", new Date());
        return "showing";
    }
}
```

Class hierarchy is: [image: Class hierarchy]

Comment: Getting 404 error. created a dynamic web project in Eclipse, that was working fine, but in this i am getting error.

Comment: You didn't even say what URL you were trying to hit. There are several reasons this could be happening which are covered in hundreds of questions here on SO already.

Comment: I am trying callingDate.html sir..

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.html` in `<a href="showdate.html">`